# Helm, K8s: is it possible to pull values from a k8s secret into configmap.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, configmap

I have a secret created as an environment variable in k8s cluster.

Secret name: user-list

Below is what's inside of user-list:

```
USER_1: 10 bytes
```

With my limited knowledge on k8s, it looks like I can pull the values of USER_1 into values.yaml this way:

```
env:
  - name: SECRET_USERNAME_1
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: user-list
        key: USER_1
```

My question is:

Is it possible to get USER_1 value into configmap.yaml ?

My configmap looks like below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: user-test
data:
  user.properties: |
    connector.name: {{ USER_1 }} ---> I want to be able to pull USER_1 value here
    postgresql.array-mapping=AS_JSON
    decimal-default-scale=20
    decimal-mapping=ALLOW_OVERFLOW
    decimal-rounding-mode=HALF_DOWN
```

Comment: Is the secret value passed in as a Helm value, or do you expect it to be separately produced in Kubernetes separately from Helm?  You may need to run some other process (an entrypoint wrapper script in your image; an init container) to fill in the secret value at pod startup time.

Comment: The secret value is passed in as a Helm value. I'm using externalSecretsOperator to fetch the value from AWS secrets manager, and put it in k8s secrets (user-list in my case). Do I need init container in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

Kind of. You can't pull values per se but you can can grab data via [the `lookup` function](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/#using-the-lookup-function). However this is a very slippery slope to unmaintainable code.

More likely what you want is the ConfigMapSecrets operator which allows basic runtime templating using CM and Secret data.